# PhpStorm with Docker + xdebug does not stop on breakpoint

Tags: docker, phpstorm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having trouble trying to get Xdebug to work in PhpStorm with Docker.

Here is my xdebug config:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.27
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '2.0'

services:db:

 image: mysql:5.5
 container_name: mysql5
 volumes:
   - "/home/xxx/docker_projects/mysql55_storage:/var/lib/mysql"

 ports:
   - "3355:3306"
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass


php510:

 build: /home/xxx/docker_projects/php510
 container_name: php510

 ports:
   - "5510:80"
 volumes:
     - "/home/xxx/www/docker_stuff/hrm32:/app"
     - "/home/xxx/docker_projects/xdebug:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini"

 depends_on:
   - db

 links:
   - db

 restart: always


phpmyadmin:
 depends_on:
   - db
 image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
 container_name: phpmyadmin2
 links:
   - db
 ports:
```

I have configured my PhpStorm as follows:

[image: PhpStorm xdebug setting]

Remote debug configuration:

[image: Remote config]

When I start to debug, I only see "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'" and noting! What else do I need to configure? I'm running PhpStorm 2017.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Xdebug log:

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 20 -t line -f file:///app/application/modules/default/forms/employee.php -n 519
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="20" id="1240039"></response>

 <- stack_get -i 21
 -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="21"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///app/index.php" lineno="21"></stack></response>

 <- run -i 22
 -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="22" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
```

Comment: What xdebug has to say about it?

Comment: @LazyOne According to the log, it seems to be running but it doesn't stop at the breakpoint. Here is the output of my xdeug log:

Comment: That's very confusing then: you cannot see that "Waiting..." message in PhpStorm and have a xdebug log where it actually sets the breakpoint. Once IDE receives the debug connection it will not be showing that "waiting" message. If that's a clean run (not from some another container or whatever else) -- collect extra log from IDE side then -- it should tell what happens from IDE point: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the response. I sorted it and got busy afterward! Xdebug was actually working fine. I noticed that I had also setup xdebug with the same app in Sublime Text 3. So, whenever Sublime Text is up and the app is open, xdebug will not work in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 2):

For any one having similar issues,the following link [Xdebug with phpstorm and Docker](https://serversforhackers.com/c/getting-xdebug-working) will help you configure xdebug with PHPStorm. I had to change:
`xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` to `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`. 
 `xdebug.remote_host=???` is the ip of your host machine.

If the configuration is alright, ensure that only one IDE is configured to use xdebug for the app per instance. I noticed that, it was the cause of my issues. I simulated it a multiple times now and it's the same result.

Comment: When `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`, `xdebug.remote_host` is *ignored*. [Xdebug settings doc](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)  These two are two different approaches to establishing the connection.  remote_connect_back is less secure [container's xdebug might be activatable from elsewhere on pc network], so one technique is to set it to 1. If that works, then you know xdebug can talk to your IDE. Then set it to 0 (or remove that line), and google for info about finding your host's "internal IP address". (This might not be same as its *external* IP address for talking to other pcs.)

Comment: This line did the trick for me after 3 hours of trying different configurations:
`xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`

Environment: Ubuntu 18, Eclipse, PHP7.2, docker

Answer (score 2):

Several things you can try if you Xdebug was working and has stopped working:

- docker-compose down and then up your docker containers
- Restart PHPStorm
- Have you changed network? You may have a different IP address and my need to re-generate host file entries or environmental variables with the new IP address.

Comment: Re "You may have a different IP address".  To clarify, instead of using your host pc's *externally visible* IP address, use its "internal IP address". AFAIK this won't change unless you change your network card or similar internal setup. If running on Windows, ipconfig should list both IPs. On my pc, internal IP starts with `172.26...`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with IntelliJ Ultimate edition 2018. Upgrading IntelliJ to 2019 version fixed the issue documented in [Jetbrains Issue WI-43622](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622). If you look in the IntelliJ logs `Help >> Show Log in Finder` and see the exception:

```
XdebugDriver.onBreak must not be null 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'remoteFileUrl' of com/jetbrains/php/debug/xdebug/debugger/XdebugDriver.onBreak must not be null
```

Then upgrading will fix the issue. IntelliJ and PhpStorm use the same codebase, so this should fix the issue.